# Non existing limit

Tags: limits, proof-verification

I was having some fun with limits, until I encountered this:

$$ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\log(\vert x \vert (1+x^2)^{1/3}-\sin{x})}{\log(\vert x \vert)} $$

To me the limit in this case does not exists, so I tried computing it from right and left. Let's start from right.

$$ \lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\log(x (1+x^2)^{1/3}-\sin{x})}{\log(x)} $$
Here I would try to use Hopital theorem, but I want to avoid that if possible. I tried using Taylor polynomial, and I simplify everything getting to the following limit: 
$$ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\log(\frac{x^3}{2})}{\log(x)}$$
Applying Hopital I get that this limit is $3$, however I do not find the same using Taylor expansion. Is it right that this limit is $3$?

Comment: You are correct that the limit is $3$ from above, but it's $1$ from below, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: Take a sequence which tends to Zero,for instance $$x_n=\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Very interesting! Though Mathematica  gives the limit as 0. But calculations of the function at .1,.01,.01,.001 give a number little more than 3 and at  0.0000001  it is 3.04264.. but at x=0.00000001 Mathematica says it is indeterminate. Also $f(x)$ at .1, .01,.001,0001 etc. is little less than 1.

Comment: It seems to me that your result from Taylor expansion also has limit $3.$ What limit did you get and how did you get it? (This information belongs in the question, not in comments.)

Comment: @DavidK I guess I am having problems because at x = 0 log is singular so I think I made some mistakes

Comment: What happens to the log **at** $x=0$ is completely irrelevant. What you need to consider is what happens when $x$ is very close to $0$ but not equal to $0.$ What happens then?

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-When $x\to{0^+}$ you have $$\dfrac{\log x((1+x^2)^{1/3}-\frac{\sin(x)}{x})}{\log(x)}=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(x)}+\frac{\log((1+x^2)^{1/3}-\frac{\sin(x)}{x})}{\log(x)}$$ It is easy to get as limit $1+2=3$ with L'Hôpital for the $2$.

Similarly you can get $1$ as limit when $x\to{0^-}$

Thus the limit does not exist.